# Why isn't Azure Devops feed searching PyPI as an upstream source?

Tags: azure-devops, pip

My Azure DevOps project uses a private PyPI index to store and publish python packages. I saw in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#search-order) that the public PyPI can be linked as an upstream source of this feed:

> When you enable an upstream source, packages installed from the upstream source via the feed will automatically be saved in the feed.

I take this to mean that when I try to install a package that doesn't exist in my feed, e.g.

```sh
pip install scrapy -i https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_packaging/{feed}%40Local/pypi/simple/
```

...then it should see that Scrapy is not in the feed and go get it from PyPI. Instead, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scrapy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scrapy
```

Am I doing something wrong or is DevOps not behaving as promised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are including the `@Local`view tag in your URL. When installing from the local view, you are restricted to packages that are already there. If you remove all view tags from your `index-url`, the upstream source behavior will work as expected.

i.e.

```sh
pip install scrapy -i https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_packaging/{feed}/pypi/simple/
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I wasn't allowed to accept it within two days of posting, but will now.